# Android (Kotlin) - Navigation action dependent on the fragment view that is visible

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment, floating-action-button

I have a bottom navigation bar with three fragments and another two fragments selected and viewed by pressing specific FAB "+" and "-".

I have a problem because the navigation action has to know which fragment of bottom navigation view is currently on display to run the right navigation action. Has anyone any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looks for an answer:

You need to get your current destination from `navController`

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
val homeVisibility = navController.currentDestination?.label.toString()
when (homeVisibility){
    "fragment_home" -> findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment).navigate(R.id.action_home_to_incomeAdding2)
    "fragment_incomes" -> findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment).navigate(R.id.action_incomes_to_incomeAdding2)
    "fragment_expenses" -> findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment).navigate(R.id.action_expenses_to_incomeAdding2)
    else -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error, zresetuj aplikację", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

If someone knows a better solution, post it please